# How get data thorough mail body

Tags: node.js, imap

I want to read the mail body through nodejs or imap (mail sample mentioned below)

Hi

User details mention below

Details:

FirstName: "aaaa",
LastName : "bbbbb",
Mobile: 123123

Regards
XYZ